# Удаление самой старой папки

Tags: windows, bat, cmd

Есть задание:
скрипт копирует папку с промежутком в минуту. После 6 раза, он удаляет самую старую папку из скопированных и продолжает работу (т.е. всегда есть 6 копий). Папки имеют вид
`Date#Hour.Min`.
У меня возникли сложности с этим самым удаление. Вот, что у меня получилось. Но работает в зависимости от фазы луны (или ещё чего-то) и удаляет все папки, а не одну.

```
@echo off  
::bobj - откуда копируется  
set bobj=c:\test  
::bfld - куда копируется      
set bfld=d:\backup 
set /A st=1   
:loop   
 IF %st% LEQ 6 set /A st=%st%+1  
 IF %st% GTR 6 (  
  dir %bfld% /A:D /B /O:-N >one.txt  
  for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (one.txt) do set FILEN=%%~nxI  
  set delw=%bfld%\%FILEN%  
  echo %delw%  
  erase one.txt   
  rd %delw% /q /s  
  )  
Set Hour=%Time:~0,2%  
Set Min=%Time:~3,2%   
set f_way=%bfld%\%date%#%Hour%.%Min%  
xcopy %bobj% %f_way% /E /C /K /Y /I /Q  
ping -n 60 127.0.0.1 > NUL  
goto loop
```

Comment: Поставьте UnixUtils (пропишите в Windows PATH) и используйте в скрипте ls -t (c флагом -t сортирует по времени).

Comment: Да зачем? `dir /o-d`

Answer (score 2):

У [старшего брата](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days) есть ответ.